# Taking a list and using it to build columns

Tags: python

Say I have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and I want to spread it across - at most - 4 columns. The end result would be: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]`. So I made this:

```
item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
item_count = len(item_list)
column_count = item_count if item_count <= 4 else 4
items_per_column = int(item_count / 4)
extra_items = item_count % 4

item_columns = []

for group in range(column_count):
    count = items_per_column
    if group < extra_items:
        count += 1

    item_columns.append(item_list[:count])
    item_list = item_list[count:]
```

Is there a nicer way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What are the constraints ? I assume that : 1) a column cannot be be bigger than a column on its left 2) the maximum size difference between two columns must be 0 or 1 3) the element should stay in the same order.

Comment: Also, I guess the list in your question should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] and not [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9].

Comment: @Josay Correct on all accounts. It should attempt to spread everything evenly, left -> right, maintaining order and I've fixed my list, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (elegant, but not the fastest approach)

```
item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
min_height = len(item_list) // 4
mod = len(item_list) % 4

heights = [min_height + 1] * mod + [min_height] * (4 - mod)
indices = [sum(heights[:i]) for i in range(4)]
columns = [item_list[i:i+h] for i, h in zip(indices, heights)]
```

Or a compressed version:

```
columns = [item_list[
    min_height * i + (i >= mod) * mod :
    min_height * (i+1) + (i+1 >= mod) * mod]
    for i in range(4)]
```

I guess the fastest way would be similar to what you already have:

```
index = 0
columns = []
for i in xrange(4):
    height = min_height + (i < mod)
    columns.append(item_list[index:index+height])
    index += height
```

(With both of these, if there are less than 4 items you get empty columns at the end.)

Comment: o.O I didn't know `(1 + True) == 2`

Comment: it's hacky but True and False become 1 or 0 when mixed with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about using generators?

- It puts the whole thing in a function which in [itself is a performance boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function).
- List comprehension are better compared to list creation and appending. See the part Loops and avoiding dots.. in [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)
- An extra variable isn't needed for the length of the list as [it is `O(1)` operation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).
- You don't need to use the `int` function. It will be an `int` in this case.

**My Suggested Code**

```
def get_part(item_list):
    items_per_column = len(item_list) / 4
    extra_items = len(item_list) % 4

    if len(item_list) <= 4:
        column_count = len(item_list)
    else:
        column_count = 4

    for i in xrange(column_count):
        if i < extra_items:
            yield item_list[i * (items_per_column + 1) : (i + 1) * (items_per_column + 1)]
        else:
            yield item_list[i * items_per_column : (i + 1) * items_per_column]

item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
item_columns = [i for i in get_part(item_list)]
```